# Spring Boot + org.slf4j.Logger - как настроить цвет в конкретной точке приложения

Tags: java, spring-boot, логирование

Можно ли указать цвет, для конкретной точки вывода лога в консоли ?

```
  LOGGER.info("\n");
        LOGGER.info(ncInform.toString());
        LOGGER.info("\n");
```

Например, вот только в этом методе нужно вывести сообщение цветным, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода цвета, если терминал это поддреживает цветной вывод, используются [управляющие символы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Для цвета можно взять такой набор констант:

```java
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
    public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
    public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
    public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
    public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";
```

Comment: а дальше то что делать ?